# Laravel Cashier : $user->subscription('main')->cancel() throws cancel method not found error

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I don't know why this error shows.
Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cancel does not exist.

New subscription create method works just fine. None of the other method works.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Non of the method works that are included in \vendor\laravel\cashier\src\Subscription.php

Comment: I have already created a model subscription in the app folder. Is it why it's not working? or confliction with the file i gave in previous comments

Comment: Can you check if `$user->subscribed('main')` returns true?

Comment: Yes. it returns true.

Comment: I Solved the problem. as i said earler custom subscription model was conflicting with laravel cashier subscription model.So i deleted my subscription model and everthing started working just fine. Thank for comment anyways. :) I know its a stupid question.